# Sine rule is giving two values for the second angle in a triangle to be solved. Cannot decide acute or obtuse.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

In the triangle shown below, only three sides were given. I have to calculate the three angles. I calculated angle at A as $44.04^o$ using the Cosine rule. Then I decided to calculate the angle at B using the Sine rule.

I wrote: $\frac{\sin 44.04}{3.6}=\frac{\sin B}{3.04}$.
This gives: sin B = 0.5870

But sin B = 0.5870 will give two values for B. They are: $35.95^o$ and $144.05^o$
Which of these two values shall I choose?

I can put aside angle B and try to find angle C. But there also, I will get an acute angle and an obtuse angle. So I am confused as to how to apply the Sine rule in this problem. Please help. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: You can use Cosine rule or use following rule: if $b < a$ then $\angle B < \angle A$.

Comment: Also you can use $\angle A + \angle B + \angle C = 180$°, which clearly excludes case $\angle B=144.04$°.

Comment: Just a note that the cosine rule is sometimes ambiguous, because given two sides and an angle which isn't at the vertex joining the given sides there can sometimes be two triangles constructed. The general rule is that if the triangle is fixed by the data given there will be a way of resolving any ambiguity - as in this case with the answers and suggestions given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose $35.95^o$,else the total sum of all interior angles of a triangle would be greater than $180^o$.Also,you can observe that a>b,thus angle A should be greater than angle B.

Answer (score 1):

As $b$ is the smallest side, $B$ is the smallest angle, so it must be the $35.95^\circ$.  Similarly, $c$ is the largest side.

Comment: The answers and comments are very accurate. Now I clearly understand the problem.